# Challenge making code testable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring

I'm refactoring legacy code to make it (unit) testable. I have two classes implementing the same interface, as shown below. In one of the classes I have an external dependency towards DirectoryEntry. My suggested way of dealing with that is to create an IDirectoryEntry interface, and pass the directory entry as a parameter to the GetGroups method. The problem is that that would break IMyInterface.

What would a better way to refactor this code?

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    List<string> GetGroups();
}

public class MyFirstClass : IMyInterface
{
    public List<string> GetGroups()
    {
        ..
        var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path);
        ..
        return something;
    }
}

public class MySecondClass : IMyInterface
{
    public List<string> GetGroups()
    {
        return somethingElse;
    }
}
```

Regards,
Frank

Comment: You should pass in a provider of directory entries in the constructor to the class implementing `IMyInterface`. I don't understand what your suggested way would look like.

Comment: why are you prefixing I with class name?

Comment: At some point you are going to hit the limit of what can be mocked. If you create a wrapper around `DirectoryEntry` to inject it into this code, how will you test that wrapper? Is there enough code represented by the ".." in your `GetGroups` method to make it worth mocking `DirectoryEntry`? Your code also doesn't show how the `path` variable is set. Is it feasible to create a folder in your test project with a set of test files?

Comment: Just a typo, Ehsan. I've removed the prefix now.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Jack A. Are you suggesting that I should not test this method? Or are you saying that I could get away without mocking DirectoryEntry?

Comment: It may not be necessary to mock `DirectoryEntry` if you can test adequately using a folder in your test project.

Comment: Jack A, DirectoryEntry is related to an LDAP directory, so I guess a folder would not be of any help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have external dependency in only one of your classes you probably don't want to pass it as a parameter.
Better way would be to pass it in a constructor:

```
public class MyFirstClass : IMyInterface
{
    private IDirectoryEntry _entryAccessor;
    public MyFirstClass(IDirectoryEntry entryAccessor)
    {
         _entryAccessor = entryAccessor;
    }
    public List<string> GetGroups()
    {
        var directoryEntry = _entryAccessor.Do(path);
        return something;
    }
}
```